# How to use a variable in a create table statment

Tags: sqlite, tcl

I use sqllite from tcl. In order to create a table I use:

```
DB eval { CREATE TABLE TableName (Component text NOT NULL, LC int NOT NULL) }
```

Now thats nice but if I want to use a variable $TableName instead of a fixed table name I would have to use:

```
DB eval "CREATE TABLE $TableName (Component text NOT NULL, LC int NOT NULL)"
```

But I have read somewhere on Stackoveflow that one ALWAYS should use curly brackets for the DB eval  statement ( I think it was for security reasons).
So, is the use of "" ok or should I do it somehow different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of a table in an SQLite expression does not support being a parameter; parameters can only be used for *values*. You have to put the table name in using normal Tcl variable substitution, and so should be *very* careful to not let users specify the name (have another table to hold the mapping from names specified by users to table names; you've got a database, you might as well use it).

Try to avoid mixing the data definition statements or data query statements in with the table creation, and be aware that you can also use `:var` instead of `$var` as the name of parameters to substitute; that can make things much easier when you have to look things up from a dynamically-named table:

```
db eval "SELECT component FROM $TableName WHERE LC = :lc" {
    puts "component = $component"
}
```

Comment: Dynamic table names are usually a sign of bad design. A prefix is can be useful in a shared hosting environment, but not in sqlite.